# How can i use jsp in javascript?

Tags: java, jsp, button, onclick, neo4j

I have a jsp file that makes connection with my neo4j database. It also can print queries on the webpage. This is my code:

```
<%!
public void test(JspWriter out)  
throws IOException  
{  
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Neo4j\\default.graphdb" ); 
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb, StringLogger.SYSTEM);

String query = "MATCH (name {name: 'Tom Hanks'}) RETURN name";
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query);

out.println(result.dumpToString());

graphDb.shutdown();

}  
%>  
<html>  
<head><title>Test</title></head>  
<body>  
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<button onclick="zoek()">Zoek</button>
<p id="demo"><% test(out); %></p>
</body>  
</html>
```

The code above works fine. It shows me the information about 'Tom Hanks'.
But i want to recieve this information when i click on a button. So i used java script:

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function zoek(){

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = <% test(out); %>;
    }       
</script>
```

I thought this will work, but unfortunately it doesn't. In the console log i get the following message when the page loads.

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token |"

And if i click on the button it says

"Uncaught ReferenceError: zoek is not defined"

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Write a proper backend that your JSP talks to, don't open a connection to your database inside of a JSP, that will definitely blow up.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JSP directives in a JavaScript file as the JSP compilation is done on server and not on the client. JavaScript files are served as is.

If you must access some content set in the server in a JavaScript file, one "ugly" workaround would be to add `<script>` tag in your JSP and declare `var myVar = <% test(out); %>;`. Then use `myVar` in your JavaScript file. But be aware of the load order of your document and JavaScript.

```
<script>var myVar = <% test(out); %>;</script>
```

I would not recommend this approach but rather get the data asynchronously via a REST API through an AJAX call using jQuery for example (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSP expression instead of a scriptlet. Also, use a return type of String for your method. Please try this demonstration code. For testing, I substituted a simple String for your database code.

```
<%!
   public String test(){  
      return "Tom Hanks is an actor"; 
   }  
%>  
<html>  
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function zoek(){
     alert("test");
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<%=test()%>";
}  
</script>
</head>  
<body>  
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<button onClick="zoek()">Zoek</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>  
</html>
```